How to close the current window and open a new one when clicking a button in Dioxus?
I am working on a Dioxus application and I have a question about window management.
In the MainArea component, I want to close the current window and open a new one when the New Project button is clicked. However, after searching for a while, I couldn't find a way to implement this functionality. Could someone please advise me on how to achieve this in Dioxus?
use crate::components::project_button::ProjectButton;
use dioxus::prelude::*;
use dioxus_free_icons::icons::fa_solid_icons::{FaCodeBranch, FaFolderOpen, FaPlus};
use rfd::FileDialog;

#[component]
pub fn MainArea() -> Element {
    rsx!(
        main {
            class: "p-10 flex-grow min-w-500px flex flex-col items-center pt-32",
            header {
                class: "text-2xl font-bold text-center w-full",
                "Welcome to Aster MDA"
            }
            p {
                class: "text-gray-600 text-xs text-center w-full mt-6",
                "Automatically create a new project."
            }
            p {
                class: "text-gray-600 text-xs text-center w-full mt-2",
                "Open an existing project from disk or version control."
            }
            div {
                class: "flex justify-center mt-6",
                ProjectButton {
                    icon: FaPlus,
                    color: "text-blue-500",
                    label: "New Project",
                    onclick: Some(EventHandler::from(move |_| {})),
                },
                ProjectButton {
                    icon: FaFolderOpen,
                    color: "text-blue-500",
                    label: "Open",
                    onclick: Some(EventHandler::from(move |_| {
                        let path = FileDialog::new()
                            .add_filter("image", &["png", "jpg", "jpeg", "gif"])
                            .set_directory("/")
                            .pick_files();

                        println!("picked images: {:?}", path);
                    })),
                },
                ProjectButton {
                    icon: FaCodeBranch,
                    color: "text-blue-500",
                    label: "Open from VCS",
                    onclick: Some(EventHandler::from(move |_| {})),
                },
            }
        }
    )
}

